# Slow Internet Speeds with Backtrack5 R2 in VMware Workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, connection-sharing, backtrack

I have been trying to get Backtrack5 to run smoothly on my new laptop and have run into a few issues.

I have installed a version of Backtrack5 onto another laptop previously as the primary OS, and everything seemed to work perfectly. Now I am trying to install it using VMware Workstation, and can't seem to get the internet working properly.

When running the VM in NAT, the internet works but is painfully slow, to the point where installing Chrome was taking up to an hour. The internet on the host machine is working completely fine.

I was wondering if anyone had some tweaks or suggestions as far as how to increase the speed? Since Backtrack5 is built off of Ubuntu, I'm not sure if anyone has had this same issue with that OS.

Comment: Some additional info would be helpful. What is the Host OS? Guest OS? VMware Workstation version?

Comment: Sorry, could have sworn that I included this in the original post. The Host OS is running Windows 7 and the Guest OS is Backtrack5. I am using VMware Workstation 7.1.4. I two other guest OS virtual machines installed on the machine (Mac OS X 10.6 and Windows XP) and are not having any issue with speeds. Thoughts?